# Is it possible to disable cURL via htaccess on shared hosting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, curl

I use shared hosting so I don't have access to the root folders out of `/home/myusername/` but I need to totally disable the cURL library on my hosting account. Is there a solution with `.htaccess`?

I've tried to create `php.ini` with

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

but it doesn't help

Comment: There really isn't a way. Why do you want to disable it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Albeit it mostly sounds like you shouldn't use shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to disable cURL via .htaccess. One could disable that via php.ini options through the main Apache httpd.conf file, but you don't seem to have access to that. So the answer is probably No.